# Sampling from a distribution given by frequency counts?

Tags: random

I have a data set with objects x_1,...,x_N and the object x_i appears c_i times in the data. I would like to sample efficiently from the distribution, so that object x_i has probability c_i/c of getting selected, where c = c_1 + ... + c_N.

This must be a well-known problem, but I wasn't able to find a good algorithm for this. What is the most efficient way of accomplishing this, when N is of the order of a few million?

Comment: What language do you want to use? so your values are not evenly disturbed? Example: [0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3] 0 has the chance 2/5 to get picked. is this what you want?

Comment: Let's just say that it's not realistic to create a vector of values, where each value is repeated c_i times and then doing uniform sampling for it. This is the obvious way of doing it with small amounts of data. This vector would be hundreds of gigabytes in size.

Comment: is there an opportunity to pre-calc the data every morning? or does it have to be live?